# Does Islam as we know it exist in Supernatural?

Tags: supernatural

Supernatural holds by a Judeo-Christian view of the world. Whilst the Quran (also spelt Koran) has been mentioned, it's almost implicit from the shows events that its account of events are not 'true', or at least accurate.

Is there anything in Supernatural that refers to Islam further, whether it be for or against its existence?

Comment: (might want to edit the title from "was we" to "as we", my brain had a serious problem figuring that out lol)

Comment: Dyslexics of the world unite!

Comment: @Pureferret You mean "untie".

Comment: @Keen even dyslexics use a spell checker once in a while.

Comment: for the record, the New Testament didn't exactly get everything "right" in the *Supernatural* world either, but I don't remember anything Islamic being mentioned explicitly; from a political-realist perspective, radical Islamists tend to take offense at misuse of their religion more quickly than radical Christians and radical Jews, so that may factor into it.

Comment: Are you sure the Qur'an was mentioned?  I didn't see any in-universe references to it on the wikis while I was digging up my answer, nor do I remember it offhand..

Comment: @Izkata it's in the first Djinn episode. Sam: "Sure, they're mentioned all over the Quran."

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield that may be true, but I'm also interested to see if Kripke or others on the show ever commented on that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

None of the Supernatural wikis I know of ([1](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=Supernatural_Wiki), [2](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Supernatural_Wiki), [3](http://www.supernatural-fan-wiki.com/)) mention Islam except out-of-universe.

I'm inclined to say that Islam does not exist in Supernatural for 2 reasons:

- Episode 6x15, [The French Mistake](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/The_French_Mistake), establishes that the series does not take place in our universe (except for most of this episode).
- Gabriel went into hiding as the Trickster before Lucifer was locked away in Hell.  The Supernatural Wikia estimates this was actually [right around the same time](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Chronology_of_Supernatural#1_A.D.) Michael locked Lucifer in his cage (probably, that same fight is why Gabriel left), somewhere around the year 0.  *(I'm inclined to disagree with the specific date, see below)*

Basic date-less timeline given the above:

**1)** Lucifer creates demon-Lilith in rebellion against God.
**2)** Michael casts Lucifer into the Cage.
**2a)** Gabriel hides on Earth, sick of the fighting between his brothers - impressions given are that it was during the beginning of the fight that locked Lucifer away.  If nothing else, it was before the fighting stopped due to Lucifer's imprisonment.
**3)** We know [Jesus](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Jesus) existed in that universe, as does the Bible, which seems to be the same as ours.
**4)** The Rising of the Witnesses, the other Seals on Lucifer's cage, the Apocalypse, all of that was written into the Bible - in-universe, Bobby figured it all out from the Book of Revelations, if I recall correctly.
**5)** The Qur'an is supposed to be revealed to Muhammad [a couple centuries later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qur%27an); however, Gabriel is already in hiding.
**5a)** Without the Qur'an, and Muhammad becoming a prophet, I doubt Islam ever came about.

**EDIT:**  Well, it looks like the Qur'an was indeed mentioned in one episode - the transcript uses the spelling "Koran", as do the [wikis](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/What_Is_And_What_Should_Never_Be).  Sooo, jumping into theory-land, I would guess that one of the other angels took Gabriel's place, but wasn't as effective in revealing the word of god in that universe as Gabriel would have been, so Islam isn't as well-known as it is in our universe.

Comment: I have one issue with that: [SAM I don't know. I guess they're powerfull enough. But not exactly like Barbara Eden and the harem pants. I mean, Djinn have been feeding off people for centuries. They're all over the Koran.](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=2.20_What_Is_and_What_Should_Never_Be_(transcript))

Comment: @Pureferret Aha, under that spelling it apparently shows up exactly twice in all 7 seasons, both in that transcript.  So jumping into theory, I'll surmise that someone took the place of Gabriel, but perhaps was not as effective in revealing the word of god?

Comment: Not as effective? As in, as he was in this universe? Perhaps, it's certainly a theory.

Comment: For a project I'm working on, I've enumerated all the angels in various Abrahamic traditions. And let me tell you, there is a *%$#$#load of angels. Hundreds are named. Many spelling variations. Castiel has 3 or 4, Gabriel as many, not even counting the arabic form (off the top of my head, Jabreel?). It's not even clear if the spelling variations are just that or if they're separate angels with similar names. So it's entirely possible the Koran gets it wrong, or is referring to another similarly named angel.

Comment: @johno IRL, it's the same angel, just a different spelling. Same way its the same Jesus (isa), Moses (musa) etc.

Comment: @Pureferret I disagree. Identity isn't that simple. One can make the case that Jabreel is the same *name* as Gabriel, but how many Johns are there in the world? We're not all the same person either, even though the name would be the same. Spelling variations can be used to differentiate us.

Comment: @JohnO On the other hand, transliteration is a bitch.  I find it more believable that a lot of these "different" names are the same one, translated by different people at different points in history.  I mean, just take a look at the name of the Koran:  It's also spelled Quran, Qur'an, Coran, and Kuran.  To a native English speaker, all of these are pronounced differently - but were all transliterated from the same Arabic word.

Comment: Most of those alternate transliterations are due to political correctness in the last thirty years. It's why when I was growing up it was Peking and now it's Beijing. While certainly some of that happened throughout history, it's inevitable that a god that creates thousands of angels is going to run out of truly unique sounding names. He sort of did that George Foreman thing, so to speak.

Comment: "*Michael locked Lucifer in his cage (probably, that same fight is why Gabriel left), somewhere around the year 0.*"  I'm assuming you mean 0 "AD" (which didn't actually exist anyway, the year 1 AD was preceded by the year 1 BC - retroactively named, of course.)  But this was the time when Jesus was born and died, not the time when Lucifer was caged.  Lucifer would have been caged in The Fall, which would be about 4000 years earlier, if I'm not mistaken.  Closer to when mankind was kicked out of Eden than when Jesus came to save us.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, jinn (demons that can be good or evil, Muslims/Christians/Jewish people or disbelievers) were created and populated the earth before humans. They are the first to enjoy free will, but because of their mischief and wars God ordered angels to destroy them, except some who had taking refuge in remote islands and mountains. Azazel, a devote demon that was elevate to the rank of the chief of angels in the lowest heaven was also spared. Angels have no will so technically Azazel/Lucifer cannot rebel.

Then god decided to populate the earth again with man, and ordered angels to bow before his new, best creation. Azazel rebelled because of his free will, and because he was created from pure fire he sees himself as superior and so does not want to bow before a creation of clay. So God damned him and named Him Iblis the Shaytan. (Shayateen are the plural of shaytan or Satan the evil demon or evil jinn or typical western demon) Iblis means rebel, so he was damned to hell for his public disobedience.

Instead of demanding mercy he asked to live until the day of judgment. He will then take revenge on those he blames for his fate: mankind. He trapped Adam by getting him out of heaven, and he seduced mankind and led them to hell except the devoted men of God. So there are no battles in heaven, and Satan only challenges God by destroying the religions of the messengers.

He leads men to Idolatry, witchcraft, disbelief, and Satanism, and brings to the world his final challenge. This is the coming of the Antichrist, the one eyed man (only described in Islam). **Islam has no use in this show**. This is because the
rules are solid and the only formidable facts that can be use in cinematography are the last day on earth or the Islamic Apocalypse. These may be used in another series, but here the Christian ones are being used now. The Ghuls and Jinns are used from Arabic civilization, however.

Comment: Salam, Could you please reform this answer? It's really difficult to read as it is. Jazak Allah alkhairen

Comment: Pureferret (I don't know how to reply) He's basically describing the Islamic story of Satan (Iblis in the Qur'an) or Lucifer in the series. He says demons were created before humans, but because of their nature, God ordered their destruction. However Azazel was complete in his devotion to God, so he was given a high rank in heaven. However, after refusing to bow to Adam, he fell from grace and became Iblis (Satan) leader of all devils (demons) Then he describes that Satan only acts as the evil in our world, seducing Mankind (i.e. Adam with the apples.) So he says, due to the dynamic of Satan a

Answer (score 1):

I tend to take an additive view for most TV shows and movies.  That is, I'm inclined to believe that everything which exists in our world also exists in their world, unless explicitly contradicted by the show's canon.  (Except for the actors who portray the characters, of course.  I'm inclined to think they *do not* exist down in Hollywood, unless the show's canon establishes that they *do.*)

> Is there anything in Supernatural that refers to Islam further, whether it be for or against its existence?

As for Islam, it has been well established that the "real story" of the world is closer to Judeo-Christian myth than any other, but I'm inclined to believe Islam still exists as a religion which human beings follow in some parts of the world.  I certainly haven't seen anything in the show that *explicitly denies* the existence of Islamic faith.  It may not be literally true, but even their interpretation of Judeo-Christian mythology is not 100% accurate (likely on purpose.)

Granted Islam is not a big part of the show, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  They also don't mention buddhism, taoism or any of a myriad other religions that are practiced around the world in our reality.  In fact, aside from the Judeo-Christian faith, the only other religions that tend to get mentioned with any serious content behind them are the pagan religions of antiquity, in connection to the "pagan gods" they occasionally stumble across.